# How to programmatically genrate a dynamic dropdownform in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, dropdown

How can I recreate this UI in flutter?  I really can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

```
const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

void main() => runApp(const DropdownButtonApp());

class DropdownButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DropdownButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DropdownButton Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DropdownButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;
        });
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Considering this snippet, how do I generate multiple dropdown by clicking a button, and collect the data collected for each of the generated dropdownform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://www.veed.io/view/93a27597-0acd-4bbd-8b2b-8e9237652354?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Source code:

```
class DropdownButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DropdownButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DropdownButton Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: DropdownButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  final List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
  List<String> stringList = [];
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          String initialValue = list.first;
          stringList.add(initialValue);
          widgetList.add(dropdownButtonWidgetItem(widgetList.length));
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widgetList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return dropdownButtonWidgetItem(index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dropdownButtonWidgetItem(index) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: stringList[index],
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        stringList[index] = value ?? "";
        setState(() {});
      },
      items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
        (String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the doc ,it has a class -DropDownButton class, you can use it to implete your task
[dropDownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: The problem is not just creating drop down boxes